# Compare two files and generate another on matching condition

Tags: text-processing, sed, grep, comm

I have two files, a.txt and b.txt, where a.txt contains lines starting with "zn", e.g., zn12c5b or  zn4i8l, while b.txt contains lines ending with a pattern "/number", e.g., t17v11/112 or 12c5b/450.

My aim is to write in final.txt the strings in a.txt (but without "zn") which do not match with strings in b.txt (without the trailing "/number" pattern).

For example:

a.txt :

```
zn12c5b
zn4i8l
```

b.txt:

```
t17v11/112
12c5b/450
4i8ls/681
```

I should obtain the following output in final.txt:

```
4i8l
```

note: 4i8l in file a.txt (without the "zn" prefix) does not equal 4i8ls from file (without the "/681" suffix).
I am using an Ubuntu system.

Comment: So, if I understood well, `4i8l` is in the 'final.txt' file because it is after zn in 'a.txt' but not before any `/number` in 'b.txt'. But I have a question: is just a coincidence that the `4i8ls` in 'b.txt' is very similar to `4i8l`? If my interpretation is correct, could you change it to something else? I think it make things just more confusing.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ awk -F'/' 'NR==FNR{b[$1]; next} {sub(/^zn/,"")} !($1 in b)' b.txt a.txt
4i8l
```

Answer (score 1):

The following bash script should do the job (since bash 4 or higher):

```
#!/bin/bash
readarray -t a_arr < a.txt
readarray -t b_arr < b.txt

for a_el in "${a_arr[@]}"
do 
    # remove the first two characters 'zn'
    substr_a=${a_el:2}
    isin=0
    for b_el in "${b_arr[@]}"
    do  
        # extract matches from b.txt file
        substr_b=$(echo $b_el | sed -n "s#^\(.*\)\/[[:digit:]]\+#\1#p")
        if [ "$substr_a" == "$substr_b" ];then isin=1; break;fi
    done
    if [ $isin -eq 0 ];then echo $substr_a ;fi
done > final.txt
```

---

If you use a bash version lower than 4, you would replace the `readarray` lines with these one:

```
a_arr=($(<a.txt))
b_arr=($(<b.txt))
```

Comment: sorry,erorr msg no readarray. i hope you can help me.

Comment: I updated the answer, take a look.

Answer (score 0):

An ugly onliner like this

```
sdiff -s <(sed 's/^zn//' a.txt|sort) <(awk -F/ '{ print $1 }' b.txt| sort) | awk -F'[<|>]' '{ print $1 }'
#1         #2                          #3                                    #4
```

will do the job.

**Explanation:**

#1 `sdiff` compares 2 text files line by line, -s option suppress common lines

#2 `sed` strips zn prefix from the beginning of each line of the a.txt file

#3 `awk` is told to only output the left to `/` part of every line in b.txt file

#4 another awk is told to only output the part of string on the left side of either `<` `|` or `>` char. These chars are separators in the `sdiff` output.

`<(somecommand)`  idiom aka [process substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_substitution) is treated as a file name with a content produced by somecommand output

`| sort` obviously, sorts the outputs to provide `sdiff` with sorted files

Answer (score 0):

If you have GNU `awk` (which implements `BEGINFILE`) then you can ....

```
awk 'BEGINFILE{FS=(NR!=0)?"^..":"/"}
     NR==FNR{test[$1]=1; next}
     !($2 in test){print $2}' b.txt a.txt

418l
```

If you want to write back to `a.txt` rather than redirecting to a new file `> final.txt` then you can add

```
| sponge a.txt
```

**Walkthrough**

```
awk 'BEGINFILE{FS=(NR!=0)?"^..":"/"}
```

When the first file is opened `BEGINFILE` is executed and `NR==0` so `FS=/`

```
     NR==FNR{test[$1]=1; next}
```

Iterate over the first file `NR==FNR` loading `$1` into a test array

When the second file is opened `BEGINFILE` is executed again but now `NR!=0` so `FS=^..` which drops everything after the first two characters of an input line into `$2`

```
     !($2 in test){print $2}' b.txt a.txt
```

Iterate over the second file and `print $2` if it is not in the test array `!($2 in test)`.

Comment: You should mention that requires GNU awk for BEGINFILE.